# What is the difference between Xamarin Studio for Mac and Visual Studio for Mac

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin

I have installed Xamarin studio for mac today.
I have seen an ad for Visual Studio for Mac preview.

I do not understand what are the difference between those 2 products...

Thanks

Comment: Visual Studio for Mac (VS4M) is a rebranding of Xamarin Studio and the future replacement of Xamarin Studio. VS4M is currently in alpha/preview release, it is still based upon the MonoDevelop and Xamarin Studio code and within the code base would be considered version 7 of Xamarin Studio

Answer (score 1):

Like @SushiHangover told, Xamarin Studio will be replaced by Visual Studio.

If you access the xamarin's page today (https://developer.xamarin.com/releases/studio/xamarin.studio_6.3/xamarin.studio_6.3/), you will se the alert:

> Update for May 10, 2017: Xamarin Studio 6.3 is the final release of
>   Xamarin Studio. We recommend that developers now use Visual Studio on
>   both Windows and Mac. Visual Studio for Mac has all the features of
>   Xamarin Studio, adds cloud and web development, and contains
>   improvements for cross-platform mobile development.

and this one...

> Visual Studio for Mac is replacing Xamarin Studio

Xamarin is a company that was founded in 2011 by engineers that created mono framework.

On early 2016 Xamarin and Microsoft announced that Microsoft signed a definitive agreement to acquire Xamarin. The acquisition value was something between $400 and $500 millions.

More information at wikipedia. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xamarin)